# Puppeteer not clicking on button placed inside <li> tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, linkedin-api, cheerio

I am trying to automate the Linkedin data search using puppeteer. I wrote the following script so far:

```js
const EMAIL_SELECTOR = "#username";
const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = "#password";
const SUBMIT_SELECTOR =
  "#app__container > main > div > form > div.login__form_action_container > button";
const SEARCH_SELECTOR = "#ember41 > input";
const SEARCH_SUBMIT_SELECTOR =
  "#ember39 > div.search-global-typeahead__controls > button";
const SELECT_PEOPLE =
  "#ember659 > header > div > div > #ember660 > ul > li:nth-child(1) > button";

if (process.argv[2] !== undefined) {
  (() => {
    puppeteer
      .launch({ headless: false })
      .then(async (browser) => {
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
        await page.goto(config.linkedinLoginUrl, {
          waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
        });
        await page.click(EMAIL_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(config.email);
        await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(config.password);
        await page.click(SUBMIT_SELECTOR);
        page
          .goto("https://www.linkedin.com/feed/", {
            waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
          })
          .then(async () => {
            await page.click(SEARCH_SELECTOR);
            await page.keyboard.type(process.argv[2]);
            await page.click(SEARCH_SUBMIT_SELECTOR);
            await page.click(SELECT_PEOPLE);
            const content = page.content();
            content.then((success) => {
              const $ = cheerio.load(success);
              const textExtracted = $(
                ".link-without-visited-state.inline-block.ember-view"
              ).text();
              if (textExtracted !== undefined) {
                const extractedWords = textExtracted.trim().split(" ");
                console.log(extractedWords[2] + " Employees");
                // browser.close();
              } else {
                console.log("Unable to fetch results. Please try again!");
                browser.close();
              }
            });
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(" CAUGHT WITH AN ERROR ", err);
      });
  })();
}
```

The script was successfully able to search the multiple data as per input value. But further, I need to filter the result for only the 'people' option, as provided by Linkedin.

[image]

I have tried multiple selector values for the 'people' button, but nothing seems to work. It stops the execution at `await page.click(SELECT_PEOPLE)` and gives an error for an invalid selector.

`(node:2124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: #ember659 > header > div > div > #ember660 > ul > li:nth-child(1) > button`

I am new to automation and puppeteer. Please help to resolve the same.

Comment: I had a brief look just now, looks like the ids (ember##) are dinamically generated, so you won't be able to use a fixed value - that's probably why you're getting the error message. I'd suggest finding a different way to locate the element, and try again.

Comment: @Vangelisz. Got your point. So can you suggest some other way to access this filteration?

Comment: Your layout may be different, and I haven't tested this with puppeteer, but you should:
- wait for the selector
- the selector could probably be ```.search-vertical-filter__dropdown-list-item-button```